# Vue.js / import export ES6 issue with const

Tags: vue.js

I have a settings.js file which has this structure:

settings.js:

```
export const availableDatabaseColumns = {
        accountmode : 'Accountype',
        customergroup : 'Customer Group',
}
```

Then, in my component I do this:

```
import * as settings from '../settings/settings';
```

And within the template tag I do this:

```
<p v-for="(item, key) in settings.availableDatabaseColumns">{{ item }}</p>
```

But, somehow this is empty and I get no output. When I do this, I do see the values:

```
mounted : function() {
    console.log(settings.availableDatabaseColumns)
},
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The component doesn't show your variable `settings` during render template, because you don't mount it in component (in other words `this.settings === undefined`). 
You should write in `created()` component hook:

```
created() {
    this.settings = settings
}
```

Comment: Better to do it in the `data` method: `data() { return { settings } }`

Comment: @thanksd If you create it in data() method Vue will create reactive data for settings, it is superfluous. If you write this.settings = settings in created() hook Vue will create private scope with non-reactive data.

Comment: I see what you mean and I guess there'd be an argument for not using the `data` method if the `settings` object was gigantic. But I'd still think the very small performance gain wouldn't outweigh the possible confusion over why `this.settings` isn't reactive.